# Unable to Download Map from ArcGIS Online to Collector for ArcGIS for Unconnected Use in the Field

Tags: arcgis-collector, arcgis-online-webmap

I am learning how to use ArcGIS Online and Collector for ArcGIS. I have created an ArcGIS online map.  It is properly configured to use in Collector.  I can access the map on a mobile device, which is running Windows 10.  An attempt to download the map, for unconnected use on the mobile device, will not work because the Download button is always greyed out.

Why is the download button greyed out? What could I be doing wrong?

More info:  a help flyout on Collector says to do two things:  pan and zoom to the work area; zoom to the map detail.  Then press download when ready. That makes no sense, as there is no way to tell the system that you have completed the two steps.  I can pan and zoom, all day long, but nothing enables the download button.

Comment: Before publishing feature service, make sure you have at least 1 editable layer. So make most of the map in Desktop, fine tune in Online, if necessary.

Comment: I have already done that and verified that I have editable layers.

Comment: Is map shared with the group?

Comment: Somewhere in service settings should be "enable synchronized" or offline mode. Change settings. Open and re-save map.

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer to this question with an assist from ESRI.

At the top of the "Download Map" form there are two buttons:  "Work Area" and "Map Detail" I thought they were simply words, but the are actually buttons.  You must pan and zoom to the work area, then tap the "Work Area" button.  Then you pan and zoom to the work detail and then tap the "Work Detail" button. Then, the "Download" button becomes enabled.

I completely did not get this, as they don't look like buttons.

[image]